# Use web.xml security constraints with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, security

I have a peculiar case where I need to use the Application Server (Weblogic) security context for authentication, but Spring Security for authorization. I am using `Spring Boot` to create my application.

How can I add a security constraint like follows (which would normally be contained in `web.xml`):

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>portal</web-resource-name>
            <description>This is the protected area of the application.</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Requires users to be authenticated but does not require them to be authorized.</description>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>Encryption is not required for this area.</description>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Remember that I need this to be handled from my `Weblogic` server and **not** `Spring Security`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add web.xml inside WEB-INF with your security constraints. This will work along with spring boot java configuration.

```
@ComponentScan   
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(Application.class);
   }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false" version="3.0">

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>portal</web-resource-name>
            <description>This is the protected area of the application.</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Requires users to be authenticated but does not require them to be authorized.</description>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>Encryption is not required for this area.</description>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```