# Directory traversal issue occurs while using spring boot 1.5.8 ,Spring 4.3.21.RELEASE, tomcat 8.5.35

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat8

I am facing  Directory traversal issue when use Spring-boot web application with version 1.5.8, only in package of .war extension.

Project Structure.

```
app.war-->
      ->css
      ->images
      ->js
      ->META-INF
      ->org-
            ->springframework->boot->loader->jar->Bytes.class
      ->WEB-INF

in which directly able to access. 
http://localhost:3737/app/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class


If I used 2.x of spring-boot then the issue is not comming.

Spring-boot-->1.5.8.RELEASE
Spring-mvc-->4.3.25.RELEASE
Spring-Security-->security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE
Tomcat-->tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar
```

For same, I am trying to use Use web.xml security constraints with Spring Boot to prevent access .
[Use web.xml security constraints with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285665/use-web-xml-security-constraints-with-spring-boot)
but same is not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve the formatting of the question for it to be more easy to read. The description of the question shouldn't use the markdown for code fragments. See more info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour was [improved in Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5550). Spring Boot 1.5 [reached the end of its supported life in August 2019](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019) so, ideally, you should upgrade to Spring Boot 2.x. At the time of writing, 2.4.x and 2.5.x are the supported generations.

If you are stuck on Spring Boot 1.5, your options are somewhat limited. You could use jar packaging or you could build a normal war file (one that cannot be run with `java -jar`) and deployed it to Tomcat (or another servlet container). You may also be able to use a `Filter` to respond to the unwanted requests with a 404.