# How config different tomcat connector server different resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

In my spring boot application,i want create two tomcat connectors,one connector server https and one server http,i want http connector just server only health check url GET `/api/healh`,how should i config?

my codes like this:

```java
@Component
public class TlsServerConfigure implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        TomcatConnectorCustomizer httpsCustomizer = connector -> {
            Http11NioProtocol httpProtocol = (Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler();
            httpProtocol.setAddress(getBindHost());
            httpProtocol.setPort(8090);
            httpProtocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
            httpProtocol.setKeystoreFile(getKeystoreFile());
            httpProtocol.setKeystorePass("123456");
            httpProtocol.setKeyAlias("tls-server");

            connector.setScheme("https");
        };

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(httpsCustomizer);

        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
    }

    private Connector createHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the accepted answer for this: [Use web.xml security constraints with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285665/use-web-xml-security-constraints-with-spring-boot)

You might have to tweak it for your case.

```
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

The `<transport-gurantee>` tag handles HTTPS auto-redirect. You can set it NONE for your health API.

Comment: thanks very much,can you help me modify my code？